# In Python (Pandas), How to generate a crosstab of categorical values like this?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe like this

```
    device_id   content
    a            X
    a            Z
    b            Y
    c            X
    c            Y
    d            Z
    e            Z
    e            Y
    e            X
```

It contains data of various content accessed by a device. There can be duplicate values in both the columns. I want to generate a cross tab where a cell `[i,j]` in the table represents how many people (device id) have accessed both contents `i` and `j`. Like this -

```
        X   Y   Z
    X   0   2   1
    Y   2   0   1
    Z   1   1   0
```

For example, table[X,Y] = 2 tells me that 2 people have watched both X and Y. How do I generate this crosstab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
df = df.merge(df, on='device_id')
df = pd.crosstab(df['content_x'], df['content_y'])
print (df)
content_y  X  Y  Z
content_x         
X          3  2  2
Y          2  3  1
Z          2  1  3
```